# Domain Driven Design Critique

Tags: domain-driven-design

I would like some advice and critique with the domain driven design below.  I've included pseudocode below. The real code would have encapsulated properties.

## Concerns

My only concern is that it appears to be anemic.

## Steps

1. Create a new request with values
2. is request approved?

   1. If yes, show the values
   2. If no, show the reasons not approved

## Classes

```
enum UnitedStatesState {
  ALABAMA,
  //...
  CALIFORNIA,
  //...
  MAINE,
  //...
  WASHINGTON
}

class License {
  int id;
  String name;

  //enum of state that the license is applicable in
  UnitedStatesState state; 
}

class LicenseRequest {
  //the name of the person making the request
  String name; 

  //enum of state to which the user is requesting a license in
  UnitedStatesState state; 

  LicenseResponse submit()
  {
     //TODO: move creation of the rules out of this class
     RuleGroup<LicenseRequest> ruleGroup = new RuleGroup<>();
     ruleGroup.add(new StateExclusionLicenseRequestRule(UnitedStatesState.MAINE));

     boolean approved = ruleGroup.execute(this);
     if(approved) {
       License license = createLiscense(request);
       return new ApprovedLicenseResponse(license);
     } else {
       DeniedLicenseResponse response = new DeniedLicenseResponse();
       response.rules = newArrayList(ruleGroup);
       return response;
     }
  }

  //TODO: move create license out of Request. maybe a factory class?
  private License createLicense()
  {
     License license = LicenseIdGenerator.generate(this.state);
     license.name = this.name;
     license.state = this.state;
     save(license);
     return license;
  }
}

//visitor for the rule
interface Rule<T> {
  public boolean execute(T o);
  public List<String> getMessages();
}

//rule that auto denies when the request is made in an excluded state
class StateExclusionLicenseRequestRule : Rule<LicenseRequest> {
  public List<String> getMessages();
  UnitedStatesState excludedState;
  public boolean execute(LicenseRequest request) {
     if(request.state == excludedState)
     {
       messages.add("No license for " + request.state + " is available at this time.");
       return false;
     }
     return true;
  }
}

//rule that groups all other rules
class RuleGroup<T> : Rule<T> {
  public void addRule(Rule<T> rule);
  public List<Rule<T>> getFailedRules();

  public List<String> getMessages() {
     List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
     for(Rule<T> rule : rules) {
       messages.addAll(rule.getMessages());
     }
     return messages;
  }

  public boolean execute(T o) {
     List<Rule<T>> failedRules = new ArrayList<>(rules.size());
     for(Rule<T> rule : rules) {
       boolean approve = rule.execute(o);
       if(!approve) {
         failedRules.add(rule);
       }
     }
     return !failedRules.isEmpty();
  }
}

interface LicenseResponse {
  boolean approved;
}

class ApprovedLicenseResponse : LicenseResponse {
  License license;
}
class DeniedLicenseResponse : LicenseResponse {
  private List<Rule<LicenseRequest>> rules;

  public List<String> getMessages()
  {
     List<String> messages = new ArrayList<>();
     for(Rule<LicenseRequest> rule : rules) {
       messages.addAll(rule.getMessages());
     }
     return messages;
  }
}
```

## Sample Code

```
request = new Request(name: 'Test', state: UnitedStatesState.CALIFORNIA)
response = request.submit()
if(response.approved)
{
  out('Your request is approved');
  out('license id = ' + reponse.id);
}
else
{
  out('Your request was denied');
  for(String message : response.messages)
  {
    out(message);
  }
}
```

## Update 1 : Background

This is just a mock of what I would like to implement.  This is a simple system where a user enters information into a form about themselves and they are approved or denied a license.  After approval, a certificate is available for print.

For the sake of example, the only rule is that a request for a license in Maine is denied.

## Update 2 : Refactor Rules and Remove Handler

I've made some modifications to the example above.  Removed the Handler and moved all code to the LicenseRequest.  I've also moved the Rules for approving/denying to classes implementing the vistor pattern.

Comment: Looks to me that You are replacing missing important business concept/s with procedural, 'outside of domain' `Handler` concept.

Comment: give us short bit about the problem you're trying to tackle, ddd doesnt work without context. give us some insight into whats using this and why.

Comment: @kyri-sarantakos - I've added a background with some context.  If you need more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately some of the more relevant code is not shown, but I would look into see what code could be pushed into `LicenseRequest`. In particular, `LicenseRequest` could possibly create the `License` instead of the handler (possibly by giving it the ID).  This is particularly true if there are properties of `LicenseRequest` that are only used in creating an approved license.  These then do not have to be exposed with getters.

I would also have `determineApproval` (possibly with another name) create the response directly instead of passing a writable message list (which is only used on failures).

The smell you should be looking for is [Feature Envy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/feature-envy). In particular any calculation using data from `License` or `LicenseRequest` should be checked to see if that calculation should instead be done in those classes.

There is a purpose for data objects (particularly immutable data objects), but you are correct to be concerned.

Comment: I've followed your advice with the latest update. Did I change the parts what you were thinking?

Answer (score 0):

States should be ValueObjects for extensibility.  For example, what happens when you need to equate a state's abbreviation with its name?

It also looks like your design doesn't really have aggregate roots.  Is a LicenseRequest meaningless without a License to talk about?  In that case it should be handled through the license (or a license service), and not directly by the calling code (which could be a web server, console app, etc).

So for pseudo code would something like

```
var license = licenseFactory.NewLicense();
response = license.Request(name, state)
```

make more sense?  What happens when you have multiple types of licenses, like Commercial Driver's?

Also, for rules, rather than a command pattern (execute) you could get a cleaner solution by having the Rules as Specifications - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern